# Huffman Coding - Combatting if frequencies of two letters are equal, different codeword generations are possible

Tags: java, compression, bit, huffman-code

My compressor uses the frequency table to construct a Huffman tree and then an encoding and saves the frequency table and the encoding to the file.

The decompressor reads the frequency table from the file, reconstructs the Huffman tree and then decodes the encoding saved in the file.

The problem is that when two frequencies are the same, the compressor and decompressor are creating two different Huffman trees, generating different codewords and although valid the decoding breaks because they are different.

What can I do to combat this?

Regards.

Note: I'm writing this in Java.

Comment: Have the compressor tweak the frequency table before adding it to the file?

Answer (score 1):

the decompressor  is not suppose to read the frequency table from the file, reconstructs the Huffman tree and then decodes the encoding saved in the file. The compressor should save the word encode table  which is "stack" -- 000 "flow" --- 000,then the decompressor just read the encode table to get the word for code.

Comment: I actually found it hard to store this table smaller than the frequency table, so I opted for my method. For example, YourMethod requires Byte:CodeWordLength:CodeWord, MyMethod requires Byte:Frequency.

Answer (score 1):

You should check Canonical Huffman codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code.

First it addresses your issue. Second, it allows you to transmit only code size differences instead of a code table or (usually worse) frequency table. If you sort your symbols during the creation of the Huffman tree, make sure to use a stable sort algorithm.

There is a Java implementation example available here: https://code.google.com/p/kanzi/source/browse/java/src/kanzi/entropy/HuffmanEncoder.java

Comment: This is a good answer but obviously a longer fix. The shorter fix was to ensure that the frequency tables in both the compressor and decompressor methods were sorted the same. Originally, only the table in the decompressor method was sorted. The table in the compressor method was unsorted. This sometimes resulted in creation of different encodings when frequencies were the same but the order was different.